# Windows 98 DOS Prompt Backup.exe & Restore.exe

Tags: vmware, ms-dos, windows-98

I have an old application that run in Windows 98 DOS Prompt and it need backup.exe and restore.exe to export and import data , but i can't find these files , i founded dos supplement kit on microsoft's website (for version 6.x) but when I run it it says "incorrect dos version" , Where can I find "Backup.exe" and "Restore.exe" for DOS 7.10 (Win98) or how can I run DOS 6.2 on Windows 98 ?

(note: i'm using win98 in VMWare and I can't access my hdd when i'm booting in DOS 6.22 using ISO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those backup/restore programs are for DOS only. You also don't get DOS 6.2 to run on Windows 98...that is simply another OS.

You need to install the backup program for Windows 98. You go to:

```
Control Panel>Add/Remove Programs>System Tools>Details>Backup
```

You then check it and hit OK, and install it.

[image]

Comment: This image brings back so many memories, and I'm not sure if I want to remember them all.

Comment: @Darth Android LOL, I do not load up those VMs often but I thought the SAME thing!!